# Multiplication using Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

It may be a stupid question, but I am trying to multiply 2 dataframes , one is a 100x2 shape ( 100 rows and 2 columns) and the other is 2x1 shape. The first dataframe is ( printing the head only and has 100 rows and 2 columns, namely X0 and X1):-

```
    X0     X1
0   1      6.1101
1   1      5.5277
2   1      8.5186
3   1      7.0032
4   1      5.8598
```

The other data frame is a parameter vector & I call it Theta with 2 columns 0, and 1.

```
Theta=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1, 2)))
print("printing initialized Theta:\n",Theta)
```

The output is=

```
  0         1
0  0.0      0.0
```

as you can see  it is of size 1x2.  Now , I take the transpose of this Theta data frame and it becomes:

```
theta1=theta.transpose()
print("printing theta transponse:\n",theta1)
```

The results is:-

```
   0
0  0.0
1  0.0
```

However when I multiply this first dataframe X with Theta1 using :

```
predict=X.mul(theta1,axis=1)
```

The output I get is ( only printing the head):

```
   X0          X1   0
0  0.0         0.0  0.0
1  0.0         0.0  0.0
2  0.0         0.0  0.0
3  0.0         0.0  0.0
4  0.0         0.0  0.0 
(100, 3)
```

As you can see that it has now become a 100x3 dataframe when I was expecting it to be a 100x1. 
Looks like dataframes after all cannot be multiplied based on matrix multiplication. How do I get it right ?. Should I convert it to numpy.matrix and then do matrix multiplication?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points of failure.

1. you want to use [`dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) ***not*** `mul`
2. `Theta`'s indices are not aligned with `X`.  So you'll want align the column names of `Theta` to match those of `X`.

Try this instead

```
Theta.columns = X.columns
X.dot(Theta.T)

     0
0  0.0
1  0.0
2  0.0
3  0.0
4  0.0
```

Comment: .dor aligns u don't need .values (in fact you rarely need it); it's not idiomatic

Comment: and your last part is the idiomatic way (or better yet construct Theta like that); using .values is simply not idiomatic and should almost never be used

Comment: @Jeff Got it.  I'll adjust answer accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I am not looking at the right place, but I could not find the dataframe.dot() method here:- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id5

Comment: @sunny [dot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)